# Counting measure and measure preserving invertible transformations

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $X_n=\{x_0,...x_{n-1}\}$ and let μ be the counting measure on $X_n$ i.e., $μ(\{x_i\})=1$ for $i=0, ..., n-1$ Define a transformation $T$ on $X_n$ by $T(x_i)=x_{i+1}$ if $i=0, ..., n-2$, and $T(x_{n-1})=x_0$. Show that $T$ is a measure-preserving invertible transformation on $(X_n, μ)$. $T$ is called a rotation on $n$ points.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Can you write down the definition of an invertible transformation and the definition of a measure-preserving transformation? Can you check that the definitions hold for this example?

Comment: I agree with angryavian (although I am not myself angry at you).  In this forum, we expect you to show your attempts, before you can get any help from us.